# Cannot set css class for custom razor component

Tags: html, css, blazor

I'm experimenting with the default Blazor client project. I want to add a custom sidebar replacing the old one.

This is my `Sidebar.razor` component:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <section id="sidebar-dashboard-section">Dashboard</section>
    <section id="sidebar-buildings-section">
        <p>Buildings</p>
        <section id="sidebar-buildings-sec1">another section</section>
    </section>
</aside>
```

I've replaced the `NavMenu` with `Sidebar` in `MainLayout.razor` component, and this is the result:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <Sidebar/>
    </div>
    

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

It works. I can see the changes in the web page:

[image: test]

Since I'm defining a `Sidebar` component, I'd like to put the class definition in there, removing it from the `MainLayout` component, in order to define all in there. So I've removed the `sidebar` class from `MainLayout`:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <Sidebar/>
    

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

and put it inside the `Sidebar` component:

```
<aside class="sidebar">
    <section id="sidebar-dashboard-section">Dashboard</section>
    <section id="sidebar-buildings-section">
        <p>Buildings</p>
        <section id="sidebar-buildings-sec1">another section</section>
    </section>
</aside>
```

But id does not work: I obtain a sidebar with no style:

[image: no style]

Even if I put the sidebar inside a `div` tag with no class, I obtain the same result. I'd like to know why, since in the css the `.sidebar` class is defined in root and no as child of other components. This is the `.sidebar` definition in `MainLayout.razor.css`:

```
.sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
    color: white;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I use the `.sidebar` css style directly in my sidebar component? Is it the right way to do it or I'm breaking the rules for css and that's the reason of my error?

Answer (score 0):

```
::deep .sidebar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(5, 39, 103) 0%, #3a0647 70%);
    color: white;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Or you can make a separate CSS page for the sidebar component if you'd like to avoid the `::deep` directive